# Add p-value column in qwraps::summary_table

Tags: r, r-markdown, qwraps2

I want to make a little summary table for my colleagues in R-Markdown using `qwraps::summary_table`. The data.frame contains information of different exposures. All the variables are coded as binary.

```
library(qwraps2)
library(dplyr)

pop <- rbinom(n = 1000, size = 1, prob = runif(n = 10, min = 0, max = 1))
exp <- rbinom(n = 1000, size = 1, prob = .5)

ID <- c(1:500)
therapy <- factor(sample(x = pop, size = 500, replace = TRUE), labels = c("Control", "Intervention"))
exp_1 <- sample(x = exp, size = 500, replace = TRUE)
exp_2 <- sample(x = exp, size = 500, replace = TRUE)
exp_3 <- sample(x = exp, size = 500, replace = TRUE)
exp_4 <- sample(x = exp, size = 500, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(ID, exp_1, exp_2, exp_3, exp_4, therapy)
head(df)
```

In the next step, I create a simple summary table as follows. In the table I want to have the groups (control vs. intervention) as columns and the exposures as rows:

```
my_summary <-
  list(list("Exposure 1" = ~ n_perc(exp_1 %in% 1),
            "Exposure 2" = ~ n_perc(exp_2 %in% 1),
            "Exposure 3" = ~ n_perc(exp_3 %in% 1),
            "Exposure 4" = ~ n_perc(exp_4 %in% 1))
       )

my_table <- summary_table(group_by(df, therapy), my_summary)
my_table
```

In the next step I wanted to add a further column containing p-values for the group differences between control and intervention group, e. g. with `fisher.test`. I read in `?qwraps::summary_table` that `cbind` is a suitable method for class `qwraps2_summary_table`, but to be honest, I'm struggling with it. I tried different ways but failed, unfortunately.

Is there a convenient way to add individual columns via `qwraps::summary_table` especially p-values according to the grouped columns?

Thanks for your help!

Best,
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]
Meanwhile, after a lot of research on this topic, I found a convenient and easy way to add a p.values column. Maybe it is not the smartest solution, but worked, at least for me.

First I calculated the p.values with a function, which extracts the p.values from the returned output of `fisher.test` and stored them in an object, in my case a simple numeric vector:

```
# write function to extract fishers.test
fisher.pvalue <- function(x) {
     value <- fisher.test(x)$p.value
     return(value)
 }

# fisher test/generate pvalues
p.vals <- round(sapply(list(
  table(df$exp_1, df$therapy),
  table(df$exp_2, df$therapy),
  table(df$exp_3, df$therapy),
  table(df$exp_4, df$therapy)), fisher.pvalue), digits = 2)
```

In the following step I simply added an empty table column called `P-Values` and added the `p.vals` to the column cells.

```
overall_table <- cbind(my_table, "P-Value" = "") # create empty column
overall_table[9:12] <- p.vals # add vals to empty column
# overall_table <- cbind(my_table, "P-Value" = p.vals) works the same way in one line of code

overall_table
```

In my case, I simply looked for the corresponding cell indices in `overall_table` (for `P-Values` = 9:12) and filled them using base syntax. In the vignette of `qwraps2` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qwraps2/vignettes/summary-statistics.html), the author used regular expressions to identify the right cells (see section 3.2).

If there are other methods to add individual columns to `qwraps2::summary_table` I would appreciate to see how it is possible.

Best,
Florian

Comment: Some examples for doing this in v0.6.0 have been added to the package documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qwraps2/vignettes/qwraps2-summary-table.html#adding-p-values-to-a-summary-table